# Continous testing in Finite State Machine in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, fsm, vivado, test-bench

My component reads from a RAM memory, does some calculations and writes back to memory. I've written multiple testbenches with different RAM values which are tested succesfully. The problem is I always have to run the testbenches separately everytime.

I was wondering if it's possible to have one single testbench with different RAMS inside it and run only one testbench. So as soon as one test with a RAM finishes another RAM is used. This would also test if my FSM goes back to it's idle state after writing to memory and reads another RAM afterwards.

This is the template testbench:

```
entity project is
end project;

architecture project of project is
....
....
....
....

type ram_type is array (65535 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

signal RAM: ram_type := (0 => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( 12, 8)),
                         1 => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( 23, 8)),
                         2 => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( 32, 8)),
                         3 => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( 44, 8)),
                         4 => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( 55, 8)),
                         5 => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( 66, 8)),
                         6 => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( 77, 8)),
                         7 => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( 99, 8)),
             others => (others =>'0'));

component project is
port (
      ....
      ...
      );
end component project;


begin
UUT: project
port map (
          ....

          );

p_CLK_GEN : process is
begin
    ....
end process p_CLK_GEN;


MEM : process(clk)
begin
    ....
    ....
end process;


test : process is
begin 
    wait for 50 ns;
    wait for c_CLOCK_PERIOD;
    tb_rst <= '1';
    wait for c_CLOCK_PERIOD;
    tb_rst <= '0';
    wait for c_CLOCK_PERIOD;
    tb_start <= '1';
    wait for c_CLOCK_PERIOD;
    wait until tb_done = '1';
    wait for c_CLOCK_PERIOD;
    tb_start <= '0';
    wait until tb_done = '0';


    assert RAM(20) = std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( 13, 8)) report "failed" severity notice;

    assert false report "passed" severity notice;
end process test;
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: You can use a for-generate statement to instantiate all RAMs in parallel and test all RAMs in parallel.

Comment: Its also common to put generics on the testbench and have a TCL script run the test multiple times with different parameters.

Comment: You should also be able to overwrite/fill your RAMs from the testbench, before the next test...